# update_all not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using `update_all` to update a specific record directly on the database.  I'm doing this in a script which parses a csv file.  I know that `update_all` returns an integer on how many rows was changed.  There are some rows where this returns 1 and some which returns 0 which means that no row was affected.

```
attrs = list of user attributes
User.update_all(attrs, { id: user.id })
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This usually happens when the database can't find a specific row which, in this case, is based on the `user.id`.  I'm betting that you have a `default_scope` on user where that specific user is being filtered out.  Try using `User.unscoped.update_all(attrs, { id: user.id })`